# Keep Android service aware, not awake

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service (for detecting incoming and outgoing calls) that the user can start and stop in my application; the service can start also when device is restarted.

Now I'm running on a situation where the service is not "awake" when the device is asleep; and when a call is received the service is not yet awake to handle that incoming call.

My question is how to make my service aware of this condition without keeping a wakelock for it?
If the wakelock is the only way to solve this, then what should be the best implementation for it?

Comment: Do not keep your service running just to capture call events. Register a receiver and do whatever you want in `onReceive()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Now in your service:

```
PowerManager powerManager;
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "NOTIFY");

    }
```

now,

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        wakeLock.acquire();
        handleSERVICE(intent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        wakeLock.release();
    }
```

Comment: This is what i have seen at first place and was wondering if the "PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK" is the better choice as wakelock level, documentation states : "If you hold a partial wake lock, the CPU will continue to run, regardless of any display timeouts or the state of the screen and even after the user presses the power button. In all other wake locks, the CPU will run, but the user can still put the device to sleep using the power button". I will try this and get you noticed thank you.

Comment: it is needed because until your work is done, service can not stop. after doing work wake log releases.

Comment: I actually agree with you and found nothing else more suitable, moreover, new devices have proximity detectors that turn off screen when we take phone to ears ; avoiding any confusions your answer is the way i'll go and will test it soon after i go asleep myself.thank tou

Comment: So; i have just tested wakelock method on service and even on application level but it's a working code but it was not the problem at first place, i've added some Log.v() lines to many points and after some testing i discovered that the code was actually executed, the problem was purely graphical since i was expecting a view to pop up , that view was present but behind the incoming call screen, when i pressed home buttom i found it there.

Comment: So you need to make system overlay view, that work above call screen

Comment: Yes i did this but then my view can no more be clicked neither moved..i'am adding a round button image (like the one of facebook messenger bubble). when device is not asleep the view is in front call screen ; the only case it goes back is when the device was asleep and go active with incoming call screen.

Comment: I never implement overlay, but view must be clicked.

Comment: I posted a separate question for this, looks like no answers yet ; I'am a beginner, i learn myself and do lot of mistakes , may be i am missing something.anyways your wakelock implementation is clear and consice thank you

Comment: Share that link, maybe me and my friend can help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534738/android-windowmanager-adding-view-method

Comment: I think you should post your custom view code otherwise people can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can add this permissions to your manifest,and make BroadcastReceiver for listen to incoming call and inside receiver you should start your service

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

<!--This part is inside the application-->
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I already implemented these INSIDE the service, wich is  monitoring incoming/outgoing calls without my application being executed, i rather was thinking about a similar approach, with no result, the system (i guess) handles received call as priority , the service is loaded afterward.